# How find similar values search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, ruby-on-rails-4

How to search similar values? For instance, I find name "Allan". But I want that search view "Allan, Allen, Allin, Allister". The same three characters - THREE FIRST SYMBOLS

```
def self.search(search)
    if search
      find(:all, :conditions => ['your_name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
    end
end
```

Comment: In your example, all the matching strings start with "All", ie with the same three characters as the target string.  Is that just a coincidence, or is that your actual rule?  Would you expect to get "Ellen" and "Aslan" back too?

Comment: Same first three characters. For instance: "All". Please, help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your rule is just "starting with the same three characters" then you are almost there - just remove the first % from your search condition, and specify the first three characters.

```
find(:all, :conditions => ['your_name LIKE ?', "#{search[0..2]}%"])
```

`%` is a wildcard, so "%All%" will match "Ball" and "Ally" whereas "All%" will match "Ally" but not "Ball".

EDIT - walkthrough for setting a variable in the controller and using it in the view.  Assumes that the model in question is Foo.  Lots of arbitrary decisions made on my part with regard to the view code.

in controller

```
@matching = Foo.find_all_by_your_name(params[:name])
@similar = Foo.search(params[:name]) - @matching
```

in view

```
<p>Main Search:</p>
<%= @matching.each do |foo| %>
  <!-- render the foo partial here -->
<% end %>

<% if @similar.size > 0 %>
  <p>Main Search:</p>
  <%= @similar.each do |foo| %>
    <!-- render the foo partial here -->
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Also, bear in mind that depending on which DBMS you are using, and how you have it configured, the search may or may not be case-sensitive.

Comment: I want to name section "Probably you meant".

Comment: Allan James, Allan Jackson..... "Probably you meant" - Allen James, Allin Dark, Allister Bigfoot etc.(without Allan name)

Comment: Edited my answer, though this is kind of a different question to what you asked.

Comment: Thank you. I am sorry for my incorrect question in the post.